# Power supplying in robotics

Tags: voltage, signal, robotics

I am experiencing an unstable power situation in my robot.

My computer (Jetson AGX) and the lights (48 neopixel leds) are powered by the same source (https://www.mini-box.com/DCDC-NUC), which is in turn powered by the battery (nominally 36V, typically around 36V-41V). I think we are reaching the limit of what the DCDC source can do, since occasionally, when the Jetson is drawing a lot of current, it spontaneously powers off. It has no indication of being a software issue, rather the power is completely turned off, which Nvidia indicates could be an issue with unstable power supply.

Now, I am a bit out of my comfort zone here, so any advice on what my setup should be is very appreciated.

- Battery produces 36V
- Computer needs 19V
- Lights need 5V

  - Lights also get a signal from computer, so lights and computer need common ground

What kind of equipment should I use to get a stable power supply with common grounds, given that the battery works?

Comment: You've told us voltages. That is not the problem: you need to know the peak power draw of your system. This is a value measured in Watts, or can be calculated from Votlage and peak Amps. Please update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with a Jetson Xavier AGX developer kit on a robot :
we had a 24V battery powering 4 rather big motors (250W nominal) and a 24V->19V or 24V->12V DC-DC to power the Jetson.

The problem was that when there was a current peak in the motors (robot accelerating stongly for example, or turning on the spot on rough ground), the internal resistance of our battery (rather high) caused a big voltage drop (several volts) on the battery. The DC-DC converter wasn't able to regulate well enough, so there was still a short voltage drop of a few volts on the supply of the Jeson, which has some internal protection making it shut down when a voltage drop of more than 0.5V is observed (I'm not totaly sure about the value).

We first tried several diferent DC-DC convertes without sucess, so as we were getting short of time for delivery, we ended adding a second 12V battery just for the Jetson (with connected grounds), and it solved the problem.

So to see if your problem is similar, I would use an oscilloscope to monitor the voltage of the Jetson supply (if it is 19V nominal, put the trigger arround 18-18.5V, and check if you detect any downwards spikes). If so, you found the problem.

To get further, we would need more detailed information on your battery, the lights, and how everything is connected together. Also, you speek of robotics, so are there any motors? If so, they might well be envolved.

PS : if you use the 19V as input to a DC-DC to produce the 5V for the LEDs, you might try converting directly the 36V into 5V instead (you will probably increase efficiency, and it might help)